# In Wave/Einstein analytics, is it possible to combine query results from 2 different datasets into the same visualization?

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, einstein

I am creating charts/tables on a Wave Dashboard using a small number of datasets that I've created using dataflows and recipes.  What I want to do now is to query (i.e., somehow get data) from two of these datasets and combine these numbers in the same chart/table.  Here's a simple illustration:

Dataset 1 - unique contacts - unique on contact_ID. 
Dataset 2 - contact history - unique on combination of contact_id and campaign_id (campaign to contact = many to many)

I want to pull the TOTAL number of unique contacts and combine this with the number of unique contacts for a given campaign.

In traditional SQL, I would do this by combining two independent queries via a UNION.  Anyway to do  in Wave?  I have been playing with the SAQL but can't quite seem to get it.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use the `union` in SAQL as well. Here is the [link to documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_eql.meta/bi_dev_guide_eql/bi_eql_statement_union.htm), but it's quite weak. I tackled the same issue last week and here is my solution:

```
q = load "Dataset_1";
q = group q by 'Year__c';
q = foreach q generate 'Year__c' as 'Year__c', "Dataset_1" as 'Status', sum('Number__c') as 'Number__c';
r = load "Dataste_2";
r = foreach r generate 'Year__c' as 'Year__c', "Dataste_2" as 'Status', sum('Number__c') as 'Number__c';
result = union q, r;
result = group result by ('Year__c', 'Status');
result = foreach result generate 'Year__c' as 'Year__c', 'Status' as 'Status', sum('Number__c') as 'Number__c';
result = order result by 'Year__c' desc;
```

First, the dimensions by which you want to join those datasets have to have same name (at least I couldn't make it work otherwise). Then the next step is to `load` those datasets, `foreach` for both and then use a `union`, where you group by those same dimensions. Group_1 is the

This is how the output looks like in my case:
[image]

In Dataset_2 I have data only for `Year__c` 2017

Hope this helps. I'm also new to Analytics so maybe I could have done something better. Feel free to correct me.

Also, you can give it a [try with `cogroup`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_eql.meta/bi_dev_guide_eql/bi_eql_statement_group.htm) but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and post back here if I can make it work.  At some point, speed will become an issue, so if anyone has further tips on how to optimize this query, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Glad to hear that @ZacharyRodman. Maybe another approach could be joining the two datasets to one using Dataflow and Dataset Recipe in Data Manager. Check out this trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/wave_enable_data_integration_basics/units/wave_prepare_your_data